# Making a chat app using AJAX, Servlet and JSP on GAE

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I'm a CS student trying to do some side projects during this summer. One of my aims to is create a chat app which will be ultimately hosted on GAE. I am new to web development so I'm trying to shoot around in the dark hoping to hit the target but I guess it will be a major waste of my time. The rationale for using servlets and JSP is that GAE requires Java for the backend. I hope to use AJAX to do the front-end.

However it is hard for me to put all the technologies together to make it work. I am having trouble with the design. I don't need any codes, but rather help with the design patterns.

I am confused with how GAE works. Since GAE requires Java/PHP/Python etc, is it possible to deploy the client coded in AJAX using GAE? Do I require two GAEs, one for the client and one for the server which is coded in Java?

I am also quite lost with how to connect the AJAX technologies with the Servlet & JSP technologies. I'd appreciate it very much if you guys can provide a step by step instruction on the design pattern. Links to online tutorials will be very much appreciated. My style is to learn as I go.

Ultimately, my aim is to get an chat app (very simple one where all users can see each other messages) up and running on GAE to get a feel of the whole web development process (code, run, deploy).

Just a side note, I don't know any PHP/MySQL (but will learn later if I get the whole web dev thingy down to include database features).

Thank you all.

Comment: Try the GAE getting started quides and - or udacity Web Development (which uses GAE, Python and HTML) to understand web development using GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a LOT of stuff available out there to read if you just search for Google App Engine.  Start with the documentation and work through the tutorials.  It's not a waste of your time to learn, since you don't already understand it.

Google App Engine is essentially a distributed web server + database.  AJAX on App Engine is no different from AJAX anywhere else - the server serves HTML+Javascript which runs on a web browser, and communicates back to the server.